# Flutter widget renders with unexpected size

Tags: flutter, desktop-application

Trying to build a drag-rezisable window with flutter desktop,
but the actual window size is quite confusing
[visual&inspectorDetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhgNc.png)
size of the window and size of the widget are all wrapped at exact size in dp,

To prevent the app widget expand as the root child of the app by default,
App is wrapped with Center()

The problem is,where does the looser 144x51 constraint comes from?
How to make the window  fit exactly as the size of the App?

codes are below:

main.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_size_test/util/util.dart';
import 'app.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   if (Platform.isWindows){
     await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
      initWindow();
  }
  runApp(App());
}
```

app.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:states_rebuilder/states_rebuilder.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

class App extends ReactiveStatelessWidget with WindowListener {
  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final height = 40.0.inj();
  final width =  40.0.inj();
  
  @override
  Future<void> didUnmountWidget() async {
      print("Unmounted");
      // await disposeSystemTray();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      SizedBox(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        child:
        OnReactive(
              ()=>
                  Center(
                    child:
                    MaterialApp(
                      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                      builder:   (ctx,widget){
                        return

                          Stack(
                              children:
                              [
                                // visible display area
                                Container(
                                  height: height.state,
                                  width: width.state,
                                  color:  Colors.blueAccent,
                                ),
                                // down right resize area
                                Positioned(
                                    width:  20,
                                    height: 8,
                                    bottom:0,
                                    right: 0,
                                    child:
                                    MouseRegion(
                                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeDownRight,
                                      onHover: (e){
                                      },
                                      onExit: (e) async{
                                      },
                                      child:
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                                        onPanStart:
                                            (e) async {
                                          if(Platform.isWindows)await windowManager.startResizing(ResizeEdge.bottomRight);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    )
                                ),
                              ]
                          );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

util.dart:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

WindowOptions windowOptions =  WindowOptions(
  size:const Size(50,50),
  center: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent.withOpacity(0.8),
  // skipTaskbar: true,
  title: "App",
  // fullScreen: true,
  alwaysOnTop: true,
  // titleBarStyle:  TitleBarStyle.hidden
);


void initWindow() async{
  await windowManager.setAsFrameless();
  await windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(
      windowOptions, () async {
        await windowManager.show();
      });
}
```

deps:

```yaml
  window_manager: ^0.3.2
  states_rebuilder: ^6.3.0
```